# Google is searching AWS Elasticbeans site( mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com) but not my site (mysite.com). What to do?

Tags: search, amazon-web-services, private, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was testing my site on AWS. And it is like mysitetest.elasticbeanstalk.com. But my original site is mysite.com. Now whenever i search for mysite google shows mysitetest.elasticbeanstalk.com links but not my original site. I have done all the verifications on webmaster tool for my site.
Is there any way to make elasticbeanstalk site completely private to me only and it is invisible to google? And if there are more suggestions please give me. All are welcome.

Comment: What is your site name?  You need to make sure you've got redirects setup, CNAMES and DNS are all configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a robots.txt file for your test site to tell Google/crawlers to redirect the test site to the production site.

Example article: http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/how-to-properly-implement-a-301-redirect/

Your future test sites should have a robots.txt that tells google not to crawl it.